# Rails 3 Finding the right :id in a controller using a specific route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, routes, nested-attributes

I have my routes arranged so that when visiting the site the `:id` is displayed before the slug like so

```
match "/causes/:id/:slug" => "causes#show", :as => :cause, :via => 'get'
```

But I also have a nested attribute called "post" that belongs to causes like so

```
match "/causes/:id/:slug/posts" => "causes#posts", :via => 'get', :as => :posts
```

When I use this, everything works great for the causes, but not for the posts.

If I use

```
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
```

in causes or posts controller it always looks for the ID of the causes, and not the :id of the posts.  So if the post `:id` is 9, and the cause `:id` is 1, and I use

```
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
```

it will always look for `post[1]` and not 9 or whatever the post id really is.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to make this work in the routes, or maybe a different way to find the id of a nested object in the controller?

I need the route to be the way I have it set up, `:id/:slug...`

rake routes information:

```
                 cause GET        /causes/:id/:slug(.:format)            causes#show
            edit_cause GET        /causes/:id/:slug/edit(.:format)       causes#edit
                       PUT        /causes/:id/:slug(.:format)            causes#update
                 posts GET        /causes/:id/:slug/posts(.:format)      causes#posts
                       POST       /causes/:id/:slug/posts(.:format)           
                       PUT        /causes/:id/:slug/posts(.:format)  causes#update_post
                       DELETE     /causes/:id/:slug/posts(.:format)  causes#destroy_post
                causes GET        /causes(.:format)                      causes#index
                       POST       /causes(.:format)                      causes#create
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: What part of the URL do you think contains the id of the Post?  In the URL that you gave, I would expect :id to be a Cause id.

Comment: Can you run `rake routes | grep post` and show us the output?

Comment: @declan and that is fine if it passes the cause id in the URL, but when I attempt find the ID of posts I get the ID of causes, so for example if I try to destroy a post, it tries to destroy the id posts[1] instead of posts[9], which is the cause :id and not the posts id, throwing me a nil:class error.

Comment: So you're saying that sometimes you use :id to pass a cause_id and sometimes to pass a post_id?  How do you know which model the id is supposed to be for?

Comment: @declan thats the problem, I want to pass the :id of the posts at the end, if I set it up in the routes to do this, it still passes the cause_id before the slug, and after posts.  I want to be able to have /causes/caus_id/:slog/posts/posts_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your immediate problem, you'll want to add something like this to `routes.rb`

```
# config/routes.rb
match "/causes/:cause_id/:slug/post/:id" => "causes#update_post", :via => 'put', :as => :update_post
```

And then you can generate the URL in your views like this...

```
link_to 'Update this post', update_post_path(@cause, @post)
```

...and access the parameters in your controller as `params[:id]` (for the post) and `params[:cause_id]` (for the cause).

More generally, though, the way you are specifying your routes is pretty cumbersome, and I suspect you're making your life harder than it needs to be.  If this were me, I would do something like

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :causes do
  resources :posts
end
```

This would accomplish something pretty close to what you have now, the main difference being that it wouldn't contain slugs.  I'm not sure why you need to have both slugs and IDs, maybe you could just identify your causes by their slugs?  [Stringex](https://github.com/rsl/stringex) is a good gem for generating slugs, and you can set it so that slugs are guaranteed to be unique.

Here is the section of the Rails guide on nested resources
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

And here is a Railscast about using slugs with nested resources
http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid?view=comments

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want my routes just like stackoverflow,  id/slug  Anyway to do it the way you specified in the routes with the slug?  Thanks for working with me on this declan

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're using the id of the cause, and if you're doing `/causes/:id/posts` shouldn't you be doing `@posts = @cause.posts`anyway?

I would look into the new router syntax for rails 3 if I were you, as there is a nicer way to nest resources http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

---

edit:
use the friendly_id gem and nest your resources, to avoid confusion follow REST best practises that resource in question is at the end so

```
/causes/:slug/posts/:slug
```

Comment: When I use posts = cause.posts it returns all the posts, I need to target one so I can destroy or edit it. Also when I nest routes the way your suggesting by doing resources :causes do resources :posts I dont have the slug in there, if I put the slug in there the directory structure is :id/:slug/:id, kind of redundent as I dont want the ID at the end, especially twice, unless it's the posts :id.